# FileOutputStream inside runnable jar throwing FileNotFoundException if path contains folder

Tags: java, jar, runnable, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

When using a FileOutputStream to Output an Object to a folder inside a runnable jar you will get a FileNotFoundException

example code that will throw FileNotFoundException (whether the directory or file is existing or not):

```
        ObjectOutputStream wf = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("res/followers.txt"));
        wf.writeObject(crntFollowers);
        wf.flush();
        wf.close();
        writeSettingFollowers(crntFollowers.size());
```

However when using the same code without adding a 'folder' to the path you will not get a FileNotFoundException but the File wont be created at all

example code that will not throw FileNotFoundException:

```
        ObjectOutputStream wf = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("followers.txt"));
        wf.writeObject(crntFollowers);
        wf.flush();
        wf.close();
        writeSettingFollowers(crntFollowers.size());
```

Both code snippets work when compiled in Eclipse but not as a runnable jar, my guess is that it is due to the different pathing but I dont know how to fix it.

So how can I outwrite an Object to a folder inside a runnable jar without getting FileNotFoundException and the file also beeing created?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mistaken.

1. You can't create files inside running JARs with `FileOutputStream` or indeed in any other way shape or form.
2. The file *will* be created if there is no exception, but in the current working directory, not in the JAR file.

Comment: Thank you, I've changed my Code and it is working now :)